# Reorder a column value based on a vector within a group in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, vector

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("QuarterYear" = c("2019 Q1","2019 Q1","2019 Q2","2019 Q2","2019 Q3","2019 Q3","2019 Q3"), "Size" = c("Medium","Small","Large","Medium","Large","Medium","Small"),
                 "percentage" = c(98,2,29,71,13,74,13))

QuarterYear   Size percentage
1  2019 Q1 Medium         98
2  2019 Q1  Small          2
3  2019 Q2  Large         29
4  2019 Q2 Medium         71
5  2019 Q3  Large         13
6  2019 Q3 Medium         74
7  2019 Q3  Small         13
```

I have a vector:

```
size <- c("Small","Medium","Large")
```

I need to arrange the `Size` column according to the vector **size** for each **QuarterYear**

The expected output is as follows:

```
QuarterYear   Size percentage
1    2019 Q1 Small          2
2    2019 Q1 Medium         98
3    2019 Q2 Medium         71
4    2019 Q2 Large          29
5    2019 Q3 Small          13
6    2019 Q3 Medium         74
7    2019 Q3 Large          13
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` inside `order`.

```
df[order(df$QuarterYear, match(df$Size, size)),]
#  QuarterYear   Size percentage
#2     2019 Q1  Small          2
#1     2019 Q1 Medium         98
#4     2019 Q2 Medium         71
#3     2019 Q2  Large         29
#7     2019 Q3  Small         13
#6     2019 Q3 Medium         74
#5     2019 Q3  Large         13
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(df)
setorder(df, QuarterYear, -Size)


   QuarterYear   Size percentage
1:     2019 Q1  Small          2
2:     2019 Q1 Medium         98
3:     2019 Q2 Medium         71
4:     2019 Q2  Large         29
5:     2019 Q3  Small         13
6:     2019 Q3 Medium         74
7:     2019 Q3  Large         13
```